# Emulate an app interaction with adb

Tags: android, adb, android-activitymanager

I really want to find an adb command to start an app **and** emulate/fake some clicks in the app.

When make an logcat and do with my android-remote what I want to emulate, I find many different lines like:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1920): START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.streamtvapp/.new_player.PlayerActivity (has extras)} from uid 10020 on display 0 D/AudioStreamOutALSA(  835): AudioStreamOut: setParameters routing=1024 Standbydevice = 0 activeDevice = 17408
```

or

```
W/ActivityManager( 1920): Input dispatching paused for current ActivityRecord: ActivityRecord{2a1163a8 u0 com.streamtvapp/.new_player.PlayerActivity t86} V/WindowManager( 1920): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2b410666 token=Token{31b4cec1 ActivityRecord{2a1163a8 u0 com.streamtvapp/.new_player.PlayerActivity t86}}} to stack=1 task=86 at 1
```

I think t86 is the channel I choose but I found no information how to start and package together with some data. Any hints would be very nice.

Greetings by JustASec

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question completely, but these below lines can help you.

**List avds**: e`mulator -list-avds`

**Start avd**: `emulator -avd avd_name [ {-option [value]} … ]`

Eg, to start avd: `emulator -avd Nexus_S_API_23`

**Install app**: `adb install -r apkname.apk`

**Start app**: `adb shell am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.MainActivityName`

**Emulate/fake inputs**: `adb shell input <type_of_input> [options]`

Eg, of emulate/fake inputs: `adb shell input tap x y`

**Uninstall app**: `adb uninstall package name`